# Вертикальный отступ по центру между двумя псевдоколонками

Tags: отступы, html, css

Есть блоки в одном .row. Они располагаются по 2 шт. по горизонтали. Между ними нужно сделать отступ только по середине. То есть нужен оступ между 1 и 2, 3 и 4 блоком.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Все нечетные элементы */
.block:nth-child(2n+1) {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```